# How can Cost Basis be greater than the Amount Invested?

Tags: united-states, mutual-funds, investing, cost-basis

A friend owns a mutual fund, **Capital World Bond Fund CL A**.  He has owned it for a fairly long time, but does not know how long.  It might have originally been with a different brokerage about a decade ago.  He does not remember.

He wants to sell the fund (for a loss), and the current brokerage reports the *Cost Basis* as more than the *Amount Invested*.

How is this possible?

(BTW, his financial adviser has given him the *Amount Invested* value and not the *Cost Basis* in order to compute the net loss, but I'm fairly sure the financial adviser is wrong.  See [this SE question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/57127/do-you-use-the-cost-basis-or-the-amount-invested-to-compute-a-gain-loss).)

Comment: How much of a difference is it?  Could it be that the brokerage is not including reinvested dividends in *Amount Invested*?

Comment: @dg99 The difference between Cost Basis and Amount Invested is about 10%.  The difference between CurrentValue-CostBasis and CurrentValue-AmountInvested is over 300%.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but transaction fees could be considered part of your cost basis, but they aren't invested.

Comment: @JohnFx They include fees for both the *Cost Basis* and the *Amount Invested*.

Answer (score 8):

Reinvested dividends go into cost basis but don't involve any additional investment.

Comment: Thanks.  The term was confusing to me because dividends can be invested in anything, and when they are reinvested, it is still an investment.  It looks like the term *Amount Invested* does not match this logic.